# Logging in to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: login

When logging in, the first attempt just turns (Ubuntu) purple/magenta all over the screen and then goes blank.  If I then force a shut down (i.e. hold down the off button) and then press it again to restart, I go to a little log-in list (top RH corner), choose Login Ubuntu and then move on to a screen that allows me to enter the encryption password, etc. After that, everything loads and it works like a dream.  Any ideas?  (Pretty new to Ubuntu so please be very explicit on any answer or help)